# Getting "Class extends value undefined" when importing Electron app for unit testing using Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, electron, extends

I am currently working on an electron based app and I have a class that extends electron's BrowserWindow in an "imports.js" file that look like this:

```
const
  electron = require('electron')
  app = electron.app
  BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
  BrowserView = electron.BrowserView

module.exports.impor = class impor extends BrowserWindow {
     constructor (){
         super()
     }
    // some stuff here
}
```

I want to test it using mocha so I have a test file that look like this:

```
const impor = require('./imports').impor
// tests go there
```

But when i run the test using mocha ( cmd: "mocha test.js") I get this error:

```
module.exports.impor = class impor extends BrowserWindow {
                                       ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/athoir/Storage/OrganiKnowledge/test/imports.js:2:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/athoir/Storage/OrganiKnowledge/test/test_import.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:536:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:573:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

I already tried importing electron in the test before my class but it didn't change anything and I don't see how I could have a circular import in this situation.
Also when i try to import it in my main.js file it work just fine.

I may be overlooking something obvious but I am lost here.

Comment: After, some further investigations it seems to be a problem specific to Mocha and Electron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that Mocha does not work natively with Electron and that is why I had this error.

Fortunately, there is a package from Npm that allows to use Mocha in Electron: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-mocha

Follow the instruction and it should be alright.